# In Automagica package, activities.find_text_on_screen_ocr is not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, automation, ocr

When i try to search a text on the screen using automagica.activities.find_text_on_screen_ocr(testfile). Initially i had received,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\userid\automagica.json'. Later i have created a empty JSON file in the path. Then the following error is being observed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\automagica\utilities.py", line 17, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\automagica\activities.py", line 8489, in find_text_on_screen_ocr
    local_data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have received the similar error when i tried to run find_text_on_screen_ocr()

Answer (score 0):

I was told that this has happened due to unavailability of API key. It can be downloaded from automagica website.

Comment: Where and how to dowoload the key file? I have met the same error and have checked its website but still don't know how to use it.